# Escape Laravel DB:raw query using Eloquent Where

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How do I escape the following query in Laravel, using Eloquent:

```
$someCollection->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(`field1`, ' ', `field2`)"), 'LIKE', "%".$user_input."%");
```

I'm wondering if Eloquent's `where` method is escaping the `$user_input` parameter, even when using `DB::raw` like this. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that yes, the 3rd parameter passed to `where()` called on a Model or an Eloquent Collection will be bound in the query, which will escape it to guard against injection attacks.

Under the hood, the Query Builder doesn't treat your 3rd parameter any differently depending on what you pass for your 1st parameter. So if you pass a raw Expression as the first query, or a column name, it's all good to Laravel, it will just use that value when constructing the WHERE clause. If you omit an operator as your second parameter, that's fine, too, as passing two parameters instead of 3 is like passing an `=` for your operator.

When Laravel submits your query to your database, it will actually look like this:

```
select * from `table_name` where CONCAT(`field1`, ' ', `field2`) LIKE ?
```

Laravel (technically PDO) then binds the value you submitted in place of the `?` placeholder. As a result, any value you pass will be bound and escaped automatically for you.

Now, with escaping, no need to worry about the `%` operators, as PDO will leave them alone, and your LIKE clause would match any row where the concatenation of field1, a space, and field2, contains the string provided by the user anywhere in it.

You can test this out by passing just a `"` character as your input. If it wasn't escaped, the query would throw an error, but since it is escaped, the script runs fine - though it may return no results.

Hope that helps!